# checkbox list with filtering jquery -Only need to match first letter

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am using `check-box list` with filtering `jquery` on a page to populate all the customers name.
However, when someone types "A", I only want the names that begin with A to show, not all that included the letter A. How to do this?

```
    (function($) {
    $.widget("ui.checkList", {  
        options: {
            listItems : [],
            selectedItems: [],
            effect: 'blink',
            onChange: {},
            objTable: '',
            icount: 0
        },

        _create: function() {
            var self = this, o = self.options, el = self.element;

            // generate outer div
            var container = $('<div/>').addClass('checkList');

            // generate toolbar
            var toolbar = $('<div/>').addClass('toolbar');
            var chkAll = $('<input/>').attr('type','checkbox').addClass('chkAll').click(function(){
                var state = $(this).attr('checked');
                var setState = false;

                setState = (state==undefined) ? false : true;

                o.objTable.find('.chk:visible').attr('checked', setState);

                self._selChange();
            });
            var txtfilter = $('<input/>').attr('type','text').addClass('txtFilter').keyup(function(){
                self._filter($(this).val());
            });
            toolbar.append(chkAll);
            toolbar.append($('<div/>').addClass('filterbox').text('filter').append(txtfilter));

            // generate list table object
            o.objTable = $('<table/>').addClass('table');

            container.append(toolbar);
            container.append(o.objTable);
            el.append(container);

            self.loadList();
        },

        _addItem: function(listItem){
            var self = this, o = self.options, el = self.element;

            var itemId = 'itm' + (o.icount++);  // generate item id
            var itm = $('<tr/>');
            var chk = $('<input/>').attr('type','checkbox').attr('id',itemId)
                    .addClass('chk')
                    .attr('data-text',listItem.text)
                    .attr('data-value',listItem.value);

            itm.append($('<td/>').append(chk));
            var label = $('<label/>').attr('for',itemId).text(listItem.text);
            itm.append($('<td/>').append(label));
            o.objTable.append(itm);

            // bind selection-change
            el.delegate('.chk','click', function(){self._selChange()});
        },

        loadList: function(){
            var self = this, o = self.options, el = self.element;

            o.objTable.empty();
            $.each(o.listItems, function () {
                console.log();
                self._addItem(this);
            });
        },

        _selChange: function(){
            var self = this, o = self.options, el = self.element;

            // empty selection
            o.selectedItems = [];

            // scan elements, find checked ones
            o.objTable.find('.chk').each(function(){    
                if($(this).attr('checked')){
                    o.selectedItems.push({
                        text: $(this).attr('data-text'),
                        value: $(this).attr('data-value')
                    });
                    $(this).parent().addClass('highlight').siblings().addClass('highlight');
                }else{
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
                }
            });

            // fire onChange event
            o.onChange.call();
        },

        _filter: function(filter){
            var self = this, o = self.options, el = self.element;

            o.objTable.find('.chk').each(function(){    
                if($(this).attr('data-text').toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase())>-1)
                {
                    $(this).parent().parent().show(o.effect);
                }
                else{
                    $(this).parent().parent().hide(o.effect);
                }
            });
        },

        getSelection: function(){
            var self = this, o = self.options, el = self.element;
            return o.selectedItems;
        },

        setData: function(dataModel){
            var self = this, o = self.options, el = self.element;
            o.listItems = dataModel;
            self.loadList();
            self._selChange();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is my code.Please can anyone give any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing

```
if($(this).attr('data-text').toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase())>-1)
```

to

```
if($(this).attr('data-text').toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase())==0)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. @ Tuan Pham